# How to specify dir of shared lib with respect to $ORIGIN in runpath flag?

Tags: shared-libraries, search-path, linker-flags

[This webpage](https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2016/09/17/shared-libraries/) tells me that we can use `$ORIGIN` to bake the dir of executable as searching dir into executable. This `runpath` command can be written as:

```
-Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN"
```

But the shared library I am trying to load is not exactly in the same dir as the executable. It is in a subdir, say `LIB`, of where the executable is. That webpage does not tell me how to do that. I tried many ways to concatenate LIB but of no avail, like "\$ORIGIN/LIB", "\$ORIGIN"/LIB, \$ORIGIN/LIB or "\$ORIGIN/LIB/". I didn't find any clue from google search either. Can you please tell me the right syntax of $ORIGIN to specify a dir relative to it in runpath flag? Thank you.

PS: I'm working on ubuntu 16.04 with GNU make 4.1 and GNU ld 2.26.1.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with ` "\$ORIGIN/LIB"`. [mcve] needed.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Kinghan is right, `"\$ORIGIN/LIB"` is nothing wrong. But it is the case only if we actually pass it to the linker. However, I am not using Linux command line. I am using NetBeans. When I type `"\$ORIGIN/LIB"` literally in Linker->Additional Options, some pre-processing is conducted (by NetBeans or something else) so that it is `"\RIGIN/LIB"` that is passed to the linker. Fortunately, I finally figured out how to by-pass this pre-processing:

```
-Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,"\$$ORIGIN/LIB"
```

That is, the key is double dollar sign!